# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo este proyecto con *NetBeans* y *MySQL*, ya conecte un `Jtable` y *MySQL* exitosamente en otra ventana pero en esta no puedo conseguir insertar en esta nueva tabla, me dice que la conexión es exitosa y me muestra los datos que tiene pero no me deja ingresar datos desde *NetBeans*. Este es el código del boton `ingresar`:

```
try {
  PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pedido(Nombre de Productos, Cantidad, Sucursal, Fecha de pedido, Encargado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
  pps.setString(1, txtNombre.getText());
  pps.setString(2, txtCantidad.getText());
  pps.setString(3, txtSucursal.getText());
  pps.setString(4, txtFecha.getText());
  pps.setString(5, txtEncargado.getText());
  pps.executeUpdate();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos guardados");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(RealizarPedido.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabladatos.getModel();
Object [] fila=new Object[6];

fila[1]=txtNombre.getText();
fila[2]=txtCantidad.getText();
fila[3]=txtSucursal.getText();
fila[4]=txtFecha.getText();
fila[5]=txtEncargado.getText();

modelo.addRow(fila);
tabladatos.setModel(modelo);
```

Y este es el error que me marca:

```
ventanas.RealizarPedido jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'de Productos, Cantidad, Sucursal, Fecha de pedido, Encargado) VALUES
```

Me marca que el error esta cerca de donde hago el insert into pero no logro corregirlo. Gracias!

Comment: Si el nombre de la columna tiene espacios, creo que debe ir entre ticks, pues el espacio en la sentencia genera la excepción. Ej: ` `nombre de cosa` ` (sin espacios a los lados, que el markdown de SOtambién lo usa)

Comment: No me funciono :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahi se corrigio quedo asi:

```
PreparedStatement pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pedido( `Nombre de Productos`, `Cantidad`, `Sucursal`, `Fecha de pedido`, `Encargado`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Pues eso fue lo que te comenté, heh. Me alegra que lo pudieras resolver

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda jaja

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de agregarle comillas simples a la instrucción SQL de esta forma:

Cambia:

```
PreparedStatement pps=cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pedido(Nombre de Productos, Cantidad, Sucursal, Fecha de pedido, Encargado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Por:

```
PreparedStatement pps=cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pedido('Nombre de Productos', 'Cantidad', 'Sucursal', 'Fecha de pedido', 'Encargado') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Me sigue marcando el error, tambien me marca en pps.executeUpdate();

Comment: Pero el error sigue siendo el mismo o cambió?...porque puede ser otro el inconveniente